# How to reference an asp.net page that is compiled to a single dll

Tags: asp.net, web

I have created an asp.net web application. It contains two pages in root - P1.aspx and P2.aspx.
Finally I compiled the application in one dll.
Now I created another web site added an aspx page and refrenced the dll. Now on this page I want to redirect to P1.aspx.
How to do that, please answer.

Comment: The markup of P1.aspx is not included in the codebehind DLL. You'll have to add the Page again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirects happen via HTTP, not through .NET. So there's no way to redirect to a class, you have to redirect to a URL.

So you'll need to know the relative URL, and redirect traditionally. Possibly:

```
Response.Redirect("../myothersite/P1.aspx");
```